# Making output table of Python script tool be intermediate file to another model?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcpy, modelbuilder, geoprocessing

I have created a Python script tool using ArcPy. It has a File Geodatabase Table as output.

I want to add the script to a new Model in ModelBuilder in ArcMap. The Table output should be an "Intermediate" file in the Model. When I tried to right click on the Table to set "Intermediate" I noticed that option was greyed out.

In ModelBuilder, how can I set the Table  to be "Intermediate".

```
...

Output_file_geodatabase = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(0)
Output_table_name = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(1)
Template_Table_Name = arcpy.GetParameterAsText(2)

arcpy.CreateTable_management(Output_file_geodatabase, Output_table_name, Template_Table_Name, "")

... use InsertCursor to add rows to the Table ...

arcpy.SetParameter(3, Output_file_geodatabase + "\\" + Output_table_name)
```

So here, there are three input params and one output param which is the Table.[image]

Answer (score 1):

You need to right-click the output of the script and choose Intermediate. More info about that [here](https://desktop.arcgis.com/en/desktop/latest/analyze/modelbuilder/a-quick-tour-of-managing-intermediate-data.htm), at Esri Help.

[image]

**UPD: if the Intermediate option is greyed out, you have to make sure these things are true:**

1. The parameter for your output table in the Python script tool is Optional/Required (not Derived).
2. You have the output table actually connected as input data for the tool in the model.

Here is the working model:
[image]

Here is the Python script code behind:

```
import arcpy

out_t = r"C:\Geocoding\Atlanta.gdb\altnameOUT"
arcpy.CopyRows_management(r"C:\Geocoding\Atlanta.gdb\altname",
                          out_table=out_t)

arcpy.SetParameter(0,out_t)
```

NB: you need to run your model outside of ModelBuilder to get your intermediate data deleted (ie run the model from a toolbox).

Comment: Thanks Alex. But the issue is that the "Intermediate" option was greyed out in Model Builder when I right clicked on the Table. So the question is how to enable "Intermediate" option.

Comment: Can you add more details on how the model looks like, what are the output parameters of the Python script? Add this into the question please.

Comment: I'm not certain but I think you need to have an `arcpy.SetParameterAsText()` in your Python script tool for that option to be available.  Perhaps create a test Python script tool and a test model that uses it, to play around with and include as part of your question.

Comment: Yes, I have already set up "SetParameter" in the Python script. The output file is the Table, also set in the Script.

Comment: I wonder whether that option needs a Text object rather than Table object.  Did you try `arcpy.SetParameterAsText()` as well?

Comment: @alextc, I've updated my answer, please see if this helps.